# How to fix roll link in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility

I use [3D roll links](http://zsitro.com/css3-rolling-links/) on my website using HTML5 and CSS3.

I'm used to make [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) available for IE and older browsers, but IE11 is detected as *compatible* with 3D css animation... and it's not.

### On IE 11 :

#### expected :

[image]

#### actual result :

[image]

So the question is :

How can I use `Modernizr` on `Internet Explorer 11`? The goal is to use *3D Roll Links* or fallback on non-animated CSS.

---

Here's my HTML's `<head>` :

```
 <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
```

Here is the CSS I use :

```
/* ROLL LINKS */
.roll {
    display: inline-block;   
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top; 

    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
       -moz-perspective: 600px;
        -ms-perspective: 600px;
            perspective: 600px;

    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
       -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
        -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
            perspective-origin: 50% 50%;    

}
.roll:hover {text-decoration: none;}

.roll span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 2px;

    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
       -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
.roll:hover span {
        background: #b1162c;

        -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
           -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
            -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
    }

.roll span:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 2px;

    color: #fff;
    background: #b1162c;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    
    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
       -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
        -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a CSS trick to have a fallback with *3D Roll Links* on incompatible browser. Add this to your CSS :

```
/* no 3d transform fix */
.no-csstransforms3d .roll span:after {
display:none;
}
.no-csstransforms3d .roll:hover span {
color:#fff;
background:#b1162c;
}
.no-csstransforms3d .roll:hover span {
-webkit-transform:none;
-moz-transform:none;
-o-transform:none;
transform: none
}
/* ie10 fix */
.no-cssreflections .roll span:after {
display:none;
}
.no-cssreflections .roll:hover span {
color:#fff;
background:#b1162c;
}
.no-cssreflections .roll:hover span {
-webkit-transform:none;
-moz-transform:none;
-o-transform:none;
transform: none
}
```

As you can see, you'll need `Modernizr` to activate this fallback, which is just a colored link. And while the `[if IE]` method works for Internet Explorer 8, 9, 10... it won't work on IE11. Because Microsoft thought their browser could now handle "modern" coding (and ooooh they were wrong).

So, the trick is to use `javascript` to load the *modernizr.js* if the browser is IE11. Just add this to your HTML's `<head>` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if(window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window){   
  <!-- 
  var n='<script src="js/modernizr.js">';
  var d='<\/script>';
  document.write(n + d); // 
  -->
 }
 </script>
```

This will write the HTLM page differently if IE11 is detected, by adding `<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>` to the code. It's simply a more difficult `[if IE]`.

---

If you combine your previous CSS and HTML to this CSS fallback and this javascript for IE11 detection, you'll be fine.

Comment: I haven't anything to do this on the web yet. Like if I were the only one to worry about my CSS3 animations on IE11. Thought this could be a nice place to help.